# Set value to input field onchange from other input field

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onchange

I'm completely new to Javascript, and currently I'm trying to set a value to an input field triggered by an `onchange` event from another input field.

Code sample - input field 1:

```
<input type='text' onchange='methodThatReturnsSomeValue()'>
```

Now I want to assign the following input field's value with the returned one from the method triggered from `onchange` above:

```
<input type='text'>
```

Does anyone know how this can be solved?

Comment: didn't you try anything inside `methodThatReturnsSomeValue()` that you can show us and then we help to debug and fix?

Comment: Let's say the method returns a text value, then I just want the returned text value to be assigned as value to input field 2 when onchange is triggered from input field 1. I just want to know how I connect this, can this be shown in a simple code sample?

Comment: Add `id` to each `input`, get value from `input` 1, find input 2 by `id` then set it's value using `.value = ...`. This is one form, there's some others. Research for "JS get element by id" and "JS set value to input" on google and you'll easily find a solution

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but the issue for me here is that I don't know how to state this syntax-wise in JavaScript, so is it possible to give me a code sample of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply assign an identifier to each input, and pass the input to the function:

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput1" onchange="myChangeFunction(this)" placeholder="type something then tab out" />
<input type="text" id="myInput2" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function myChangeFunction(input1) {
    var input2 = document.getElementById('myInput2');
    input2.value = input1.value;
  }
</script>
```

You pass `input1` to the function as an argument, then we get the value of input1 and assign it as the value to `input2` after finding it in the DOM.

Note that the change event will only fire on a text input if you remove focus. So for example you'll have to tab out of the field to get field 2 to get updated. If you want you could use something else like `keyup` or `keypress` to get a more live update.

You can also do this without using an HTML attribute which is a little cleaner:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput1" />
<input type="text" id="myInput2" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  var input1 = document.getElementById('myInput1');
  var input2 = document.getElementById('myInput2');

  input1.addEventListener('change', function() {
    input2.value = input1.value;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I just tried your code on the following site: https://jsfiddle.net/ but on focus out it doesn't assign my typed value to input2. :-(

Comment: Can you save the fiddle and send the link to it here?